# Is there a way to avoid adding lifetimes to all downstream structs when I add a lifetime?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have a struct:

```
struct C {
    field: Box<Fn()>
}

struct D(C)
struct E(C)
struct F(D)
```

I want to change the field of `C` to `&Fn()` instead to accommodate named functions. I run into trouble since the reference field in a Rust struct needs a lifetime parameter. `C` now has to be:

```
struct C<'a> {
    field: &'a Fn()
}
```

Then for `D`, `E`, `F`, I have to supply the lifetime parameter as well:

```
struct D<'a>(c<'a>)
struct E<'a>(C<'a>)
struct F<'a>(C<'a>)
```

Imagine `D`, `E`, `F` have many `impl` functions... now the code requires a massive change to add a lifetime parameter to a lot of places.

Is there a way to avoid doing that? The lifetime parameter for `C` cannot be `'static` as I have a bunch of locally defined closures as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very simple way of avoiding that: just use `Box<Fn()>` for regular functions as well.

Rust has two types of abstracted functions:

- `fn()` represents "simple" functions
- `Fn()` abstracts over both functions and closures

So using `Box<Fn()>` allows you to have both.

Of course, there is a memory allocation here, which is unnecessary for "naked" functions. You may find the trade-off acceptable rather than having to refactor your entire code.

If you are intent on avoiding the memory allocation, you may want to look into [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html).

Comment: Regular functions are zero-sized. Boxing a zero-sized type does not perform any allocation at all (the allocator just returns `1` for the pointer).

Comment: @FrancisGagné: Are you sure? Surely the runtime will need a pointer to the function to know which one to call...

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Normal functions all have their own type: this type is zero-sized. However, this type can also be cast to a function pointer type, which has the same size as a regular pointer. But `Box<Fn()>` does *not* perform a heap allocation if you use the distinct function type: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6013c48297802fe6378bf391f45cc0fa&version=stable&backtrace=1. `Fn`'s vtable will dispatch to the correct function.

Comment: @FrancisGagné: Ah I see, so the pointer to the function is implemented in the v-table. That's clever.

Answer (score 5):

[Matthieu M. has answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41933625/155423) the question "how can I avoid adding a lifetime at all", which probably solves your *problem* but not your *question*:

> Is there a way to avoid adding lifetimes to all downstream structs when I add a lifetime

No, there is no way. A lifetime annotation is *another generic type* that you have parameterized your type with. Everything that uses that type must know about the concrete lifetime that it is parameterized with. One of the big reasons for lifetimes is because of this - to have a safe system, the compiler (and you!) have to know that a struct contains a reference to something that might go out of scope. One that happens, the references are no longer valid.